# Create google script to modify calendar events when they're updated

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-apps

I'd like to create a script that writes down the history of an event, i.e. when I change the date or time of the event and save it, it would copy the previous date/time into the description/note of the event. However, I only found I could write scripts for docs, sheets or forms. Any idea how to do this or did I miss something?

Comment: are you editing the events manually or using a script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no event detection (I mean "event" that can trigger a script when an "event"(;-) is modified) in the Calendar API so the first answer would be : not possible.

The second answer would be : there is a possible workaround but it has a few limitations.

You can monitor a calendar content in a time based triggered script that detects any change in this calendar and it could easily warn you about the change and tell you what value was changed.
The process is very similar to what I used in [this recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298160/how-to-trigger-an-email-notification-when-cell-value-is-modified-by-function/35299858#35299858)

The limitation I mentioned is that you have to store the events from the calendar for a certain period (for example from today to next 3 month) , which means that any event occurring later than that (or earlier) won't be detected...
For my use case it wasn't an issue  (I monitor classrooms ressources calendars) but it might be for you.

Comment: I want to do it as a part of my planning. I use calendar to plan my week and then I evaluate it and it would help me if I knew how the planned durations changed in reality.

Comment: on a single calendar and a limited duration (current week + a couple of coming weeks) this method would certainly work very well. You just have to read all the events from now and store the titles/durations/startDate/time to scriptProperties and then every 30' you compare current values with stored values.

Comment: It's not ideal, but better than nothing. Or maybe I'll just do it manually. Thanks